# C# delegate contravariance with lambda expression

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, contravariance, method-group

The second test method below does not compile (cannot convert lambda expression to target type `D1`).  Does that mean that (non-generic) delegate contravariance does not work with lambda expressions?

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyVarianceTests
{
    private abstract class Animal {}
    private class Tiger : Animal {}

    private delegate Type D1(Tiger tiger);

    private static Type M1(Animal animal)
    {
        return animal.GetType();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ContravariantDelegateWithMethod()
    {
        D1 func = M1;
        Type result = func(new Tiger());
        Assert.AreEqual(result, typeof (Tiger));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ContravariantDelegateWithLambda()
    {
        D1 func = (Animal animal) => animal.GetType();
        Type result = func(new Tiger());
        Assert.AreEqual(result, typeof (Tiger));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've identified an inconsistency in the language.

This is called out explicitly in the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> **7.15.1 Anonymous function signatures**
>
> [...] In contrast to method group conversions (§6.6), contra-variance of anonymous function
> parameter types is not supported. [...]

...which raises the question:

**Why didn't the language designers bother supporting this feature?**

`<speculation>`

Clearly, the feature has some small benefits. But does it justify the costs of the extra complications required in a compliant compiler implementation?

When you write a lambda expression, you must *already* know exactly which delegate/expression-tree type it is being converted to (there's no general-purpose type that can "hold" an arbitrary lambda). As of C# 5, a lambda (in contrast to a method) serves absolutely no purpose other than to help in the creation of a *single* delegate / expression-tree instance. Consequently, there's no advantage (other than convenience) to *explicitly* specifying a more general type than required for a parameter and expecting contra-variance support from the compiler.  You could just omit the type completely and rely on type-inference (or, worst case, explicitly specify the exact parameter-type required) without any loss in reusability or expressibility.

This obviously doesn't apply to methods, which serve other purposes other than the creation of delegates/expression-trees. You may desire a particular function signature (different from the delegate's) because it is the most appropriate, or *require* it because it must satisfy an interface contract. Further more, consider that you (as the programmer creating the delegate/expression-tree) don't necessarily "own" the method in question (it could be in a third-party assembly) when you are performing a method-group conversion. This is never the case with lambdas.

It appears the language-designers felt the benefits of implementing contra-variance of parameter types for lambdas didn't justify the costs, unlike for method-groups.

`</speculation>`

Comment: Thanks, this is the reference that I was looking for.  And your guess as to why there is an inconsistency makes sense to me as well.

Answer (score 2):

D1 excepts an argument of type Tiger but you're passing in a type of Animal.
Animal is not a Tiger
But Tiger is an Animal

Comment: Animal is less specific, so assigning a function that takes an `Animal` to a delegate that's specifying a `Tiger` shouldn't be a problem. `M1` is less specific than `D1`.

Comment: +1. Yeah. Co- and contravariance are often mind boggling and do not work the way that you would intuitively think of in the first time.

Comment: How does your answer not apply to the method-group conversion `D1 func = M1;`?

Comment: Ani is correct. This answer does not take into account the fact that the statement `D1 func = M1;` works as expected.